# Mismatch error opening excel workbook in outlook vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have researched this and not finding anything. Shouldn't be that difficult to solve. I am trying to open an Excel workbook with VBA in Outlook but it is throwing a mismatch error and I don't know how to fix.

```
Function openWorkbook()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim sourceWB As Excel.Application

Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Stress Test\GSST Daily\weekly report\June\GSST Daily Estimation week of 06.22.xlsx")

End Function
```

Comment: I have the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library turned on as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your variable declarations. Since you're using early binding, this is pretty straightforward. Also I'd change this to a `Sub` if you're not planning to return anything.

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim sourceWb As Excel.Workbook

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set sourceWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Stress Test\GSST Daily\weekly report\June\GSST Daily Estimation week of 06.22.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Comment: This code does not work for me. I got a run-time error 91. Object variable or With block variable not set.